# c# Assignment operator &=

Tags: c#, assignment-operator

if I have the following bool:

```
bool success = true;
```

Will the following three lines of code store the same results in success:

```
1 - success &= SomeFunctionReturningABool();

2 - success = success & SomeFunctionReturningABool();

3 - success = success && SomeFunctionReturningABool();
```

I found an article stating that 1 is a shortcut for 2 - but is 2 the same as 3 or is my application going to explode on execution of this line...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For boolean type, single `&` evaluates all operands, while double `&&` only evaluates while necessary (i.e. if the first operand is false, it won't bother to evaluate the second one), also known as "short-circuit" evaluation.

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2a723cdk(v=vs.80).aspx

As for the `&=` assignment operator, it works same as single `&`.

Comment: Great thanks! so that would mean that if success was false the 3rd line would not execute the function?

Answer (score 2):

1 and 2 are the same in the same way that the following are the same:

```
int value += 1;
int value = value + 1;
```

3 is not the same, as if `success` is false, `SomeFunctionReturningABool()` **won't** get called - which is not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You are right. 1 is a shortcut to 2.
The difference between '&' and '&&' you can find here [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2a723cdk%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

'&' is a logical AND while '&&' is conditional AND

Answer (score -1):

Options 2 and 3 are equivalent, and `&=` does exactly that.

You should know that if the first call fails, the subsequent calls might not occur: for example,

```
if (x != null && x.Test() == true)
```

It evaluates `x != null` first - and if it's false then the second part won't get executed.  The same may apply here.

(Huh, I wonder if that's just for && and not &...)

Comment: No, 2 and 3 are NOT equivalent. The single ampersand would actually evaluate BOTH arguments, unlike, as you noted, the double ampersand. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2a723cdk(v=vs.80).aspx